# Comparing Age Ranges - Control Group

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval

I have a dataset of people who have taken an exam, some of which have passed, and some of which have failed. I have grouped the people into age ranges (18-24, 25-34, 35-44 etc).

I'm comparing whether people aged 35-44 are more likely to pass than the other age groups. My variation group is the group aged 35-44. Should my control group be either (a) all ages, or (b) all ages except people aged 35-44?

Comment: Although in theory one might be able to conduct a useful test of the 35-44 group against all ages, it would be difficult.  The reason is that the "all ages" data *include* the 35-44 year data.  This induces a statistical *dependence* between statistics for the two groups.  As a result, it would be invalid to apply any standard test to make the comparison, because all such tests require *independence.* It's far simpler, both conceptually and theoretically, to compare *disjoint* groups of data rather than overlapping groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Control group should definitely *not* be "(a) all ages", as that would be plainly wrong. For a two-sample hypothesis you should have:

- Group 1: all ages except people aged 35-44
- Group 2: people aged 35-44

For multiple sample comparison you may involve GLM and post-hoc testing with a different experimental setup.